# Add a last-updated timestamp to a FoxPro table

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm synchronizing data between FoxPro and a remote SQL Server.  Everything is working great, but on the FoxPro side, it would be much faster if I could detect records that don't need to be considered for sync.  I calculate a hash off values to compare against the last-known hash, so with loaded records it's easy enough.  What I would like to do is filter out records prior to even loading them by checking an `updated` column against the start time of the last sync.

How do I add an `updated` column to a VFP 9 table that gets filled in with the current date and time whenever a change is made to the row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the table is in a VFP database (that is, is not a free table), add a datetime column to the table and set up a table rule to populate the field. Assuming you have VFP available, you can do this in the Table Designer or with code.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD tUpdated T
ALTER TABLE YourTable SET CHECK YourFunction()
```

As the syntax indicates, you need to define a function (or a stored procedure in the VFP database) to actually run when the rule fires. You want it to return true. The code in the function can be as simple as:

```
REPLACE tUpdated WITH DATETIME()
RETURN .T.
```

Tamar

Comment: Thanks. I can't programmatically add stored procedures (this bit of code gets executed at runtime from a distributed .exe, and `APPEND PROCEDURES` is only valid from within the IDE), so I used `SET CHECK EXECSCRIPT("REPLACE tUpdated WITH DATETIME()")`.